# Recycle remote IIS app pool from the command line?

Tags: command-line-interface, powershell, iis, iis-7, winrm

Is it possible to recycle an IIS7 app pool from the command line, on a different machine?

I've found APPCMD (`appcmd recycle apppool my-app-pool`), but it only operates on the host it's run on, AFAICT.

I heard a rumor there might be a way to do it with Powershell, but I know nothing about that, and I'm apparently not very good at googling for it.

I'm using Vista / Server 2008, if that matters.

EDIT: I found something called [WinRM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781778(WS.10).aspx) that somebody claims is able to run APPCMD itself, but I'm not sure exactly how, yet.

Answer (score 30):

Ken, if this is run from CMD you could do it with [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649). This requires no installation on the server you want to access.

Simply copy the contents of the [zip](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) to your System32 file (don't include the ELUA or the DLL file) of the computer you want to remote FROM.
Then [enter CMD](http://commandwindows.com/runline.htm)
type
`Psexec \\{Computer Name of ISS7 Server} %systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd recycle apppool my-app-pool`

If you are not on the same domain on an domain admin account you will need to enter credentials for administrative access. For more information simply type psexec in a command line with no arguments.

Comment: AppCmd.exe location (%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\) is not part of the PATH automatically. You can either add it to your path or run appcmd with: "%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe"

Comment: You don't quote the remote command for PsExec; you send in the command name followed by the arguments all separated by spaces.  So command should be be: `Psexec \\computer c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" recycle apppool AppPoolName`

Answer (score 6):

To do it remotely from PowerShell you need to either use PowerShell remoting, or use WMI.

It's actually very simple using the Invoke-WMIMethod PowerShell cmdlet, but you have to specify `-Authentication PacketPrivacy`  ... and if you need to specify different credentials, you can do that with parameter `-Credential (Get-Credential)` ... here's an example:

```
$pc = "serverName"

## List the app pools, note the __RELPATH of the one you want to kill:
Get-WMIObject IISApplicationPool 
              -Computer $pc 
              -Namespace root\MicrosoftIISv2 
              -Authentication PacketPrivacy 

## Recycle a specific one:
$Name = "W3SVC/APPPOOLS/ASP.NET v4.0 Classic"  ## This is the Name from above
$Path = "IISApplicationPool.Name='$Name'"      ## This is the __RELPATH

Invoke-WMIMethod Recycle 
                 -Path $Path 
                 -Computer $pc 
                 -Namespace root\MicrosoftIISv2 
                 -Authentication PacketPrivacy
```

I wrote a nice function to wrap all that up: http://poshcode.org/2466

Comment: You may need to enable "IIS 6 WMI Compatibility" on IIS7 for the root\MicrosoftIISv2 namespace to be available. http://forums.iis.net/t/1158882.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If command line is your choise, [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) seems to be the solution, but for mission critical tasks I wouldn't recommend it. The reason is the following: PsExec has [problems](http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-launching-multiple-processes_topic19120.html) with multiple runs. 
I prefer to use API for such purposes.

1. WMI will do the job as it is described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/padmanr/archive/2010/05/08/execute-a-process-on-remote-machine-wait-for-it-to-exit-and-retrieve-its-exit-code-using-wmi.aspx) (my favourite solution).
2. Alternatively you can use [ServerManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) API. It allows to manage application pools on **remote** machine if you run your code with corresponding credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Jeff's answer, with Powershell remoting it would be:

`Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <your server> -Credential <username, or (Get-Credential)>`

Then in the interactive session, then:

`appcmd recycle apppool my-app-pool`

to restart the app pool.

Answer (score 0):

Recycle AppPool in PowerShell

In this example: MSExchangeSyncAppPool

```
$appPool = Get-WmiObject -Authentication PacketPrivacy -Impersonation Impersonate -ComputerName (hostname) -namespace "root/MicrosoftIISv2" -class IIsApplicationPool | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "W3SVC/AppPools/MSExchangeSyncAppPool" }
$appPool.Recycle()
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, there is also [ADSI Service Provider for IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525929(v=vs.90)) (Warning: Outdated technology):

```perl
$ComputerName = 'webserver01.local'
$AppPool = 'MyWebPortalPool'

# Load System.DirectoryServices assembly if not already loaded:
if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry').Type) {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices
}

$PoolPath = "IIS://$ComputerName/W3SVC/AppPools/$AppPool"

$PoolObj = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($PoolPath)
$PoolObj.Invoke('Recycle', $null)

$PoolObj.Dispose()
```